# Change the state of a checkbox on Form2 and keep the state

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

All I am trying to do is to change the state of checkbox on form2, and keep the state after pression OK. 
I have form1 which is my main form and it only has one Strip menu. The code for form1 is as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void dialogToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 dialog = new Form2();

            dialog.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

The Form2 only has one checkbox and one OK button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (cbxForm2.Checked == true)
            {
                cbxForm2.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change my code so when I go back on the menu the state of the combo box is as I left it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `Form2` every time:

```
private void dialogToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // the 'new' keyword means you are creating an entirely new instance
    Form2 dialog = new Form2();
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

This new instance has no idea what any previous instances looked like, so you need to store the state of the `CheckBox` and assign the value when you open `Form2`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // backing field to store the state
    bool checkBoxChecked;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void dialogToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 dialog = new Form2();

        // assign the state
        dialog.CheckBoxChecked = this.checkBoxChecked;
        dialog.ShowDialog();

        // save the state
        this.checkBoxChecked = dialog.CheckBoxChecked;
    }
}
```

You also need to add a property on `Form2` so you can retrieve the state:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool CheckBoxChecked
    {
        get { return cbxForm2.Checked; }
        set { cbxForm2.Checked = value; }
    }
}
```